# How to eliminate whitespace in pyplot heatmaps?

Tags: matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to make a heatmap using pcolor in pyplot

```
data=np.array(old_data)
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
mymap=ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
ax.autoscale(tight=True)
plt.show()
```

for some reason I keep getting blank white columns between the heatmap columns:
[image]

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What is `data`? Does it have columns of zeros in it?

Comment: Try this: `plt.pcolor(data[:,::2], cmap=plt.cm.Blues)`